# vaadin : multiple links in one field on the table

Tags: vaadin

I want to ask about the UI of the vaadin, which is Table.
If I used this component, then I have to create a field using this command:

```
userTable.addContainerProperty("Status", String.class, "Active");
```

If I want to create link into this field, then I have to do like this:

```
userTable.addContainerProperty("Action", Link.class, new Link("Remove", new ExternalResource("#")));
```

My question is, the example above, only display single link in one field which is REMOVE Link. I want to create two links in one field of that table. For example link for EDIT and DELETE below the "Action" field, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a generated column to add the components to each row. Create an Horizontal Layout and two Buttons as the content.

```
class ValueColumnGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator {
String format; /* Format string for the Double values. */

/**
 * Creates double value column formatter with the given
 * format string.
 */
public ValueColumnGenerator(String format) {
    this.format = format;
}

/**
 * Generates the cell containing the Double value.
 * The column is irrelevant in this use case.
 */
public Component generateCell(Table source, Object itemId,
                              Object columnId) {
    // Get the object stored in the cell as a property
    Property prop =
        source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId);
    if (prop.getType().equals(Double.class)) {
        HorizontalLayout hbox = new HorizontalLayout()
        hbox.addComponent(new Button("Status"))
        hbox.addComponent(new Button("Remove"))
        return hbox;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

See Section 5.14.5 of the Book of Vaadin for more info:

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html

Comment: you may find this link useful when implementing a custom cell with buttons: http://morevaadin.com/content/separation-of-concerns/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this buttons to HorizontalLayout or any other container component. Then add this layout to the container property in your table.